# RailsJS get Variables in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

in my index.html.erb i'd like to save my settings to the database.

My settings are stored here

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
window.settings = <%= raw Setting.where("shopify_domain = '#{@currentShop.domain}'").to_json %>
<% end %>
```

Now i'd like to write back my settings to the database by calling this function

```
function writeSettings() {

  alert(settings[0].id); //this is working

  <%=  Setting.update(settings[0].id, :appearance => 'box') %> //not working unknown variable settings

}
```

How can i update my record?

Or, how can i call this function with parameters in my settings.rb file

```
# PATCH/PUT /settings/1
# PATCH/PUT /settings/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @setting.update(setting_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @setting, notice: 'Setting was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @setting }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: You need to get your JS to update your html - then pluck the value of the id from the html using div selectors - if you have your setting_id stored in a div 'setting-id' then you need: document.getElementById("school_id_school_id").value

Comment: can you send me a working example? i don't get it :( So this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8109345 is what im looking for?

Comment: Sorry ignore the above will give a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

https://jing.io/t/pass-javascript-variables-to-rails-controller.html

There's probably better ways to approach it but that link should get your method working

Comment: Sorry but, none of these methods are working with the latest rails version

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you must reload the page in order for the controller methods to be used. So, you can't just call it in the middle of the page, after the page has completely loaded. You need to use the client to send the call to the server. In your function, instead of rails, do an ajax call.

Here's a good starter method:

```
       $.ajax({
            url: '/settings/' + settings[0].id,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                setting: {
                    appearance: 'box,
                }
            },
            success: function(result)   {
                console.log('success!')
            },
            error: function(err)    {
                console.log(err);
            }
```